# Unix time command implementation

Tags: unix

I want to know about the time command flow of execution.

I have a doubt in the time calculation for the command execution.

1. Whether the real time is sum of (time taken to open the unix window + execute the command given infront of the "time" command + close the unix window)
2. or Just the time taken for executing the same command in the same window.

If u have time command source code, mail me.

Please help Me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

GNU implementation of time, with source, is available [Free Software Directory](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Time).